# F# Fable function from imported module is not compiled into js

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I use SAFE stack. For email validation I imported EmailValidation via paket. Code compiles and runs; I can even peek into EmailValidation sources via debugger. At run time I face an exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: EmailValidation_EmailValidator_Validate_C556D7B is not defined
    at isEmailAndPasswordValid (Index.fs.js?b47d:47)
    at containerBox (Index.fs.js?b47d:184)
    at view (Index.fs.js?b47d:216)
    at eval (App.fs.js?8a0c:24)
    at eval (Util.js?2ca6:555)
    at uncurriedFn (Util.js?2ca6:520)
    at Object.eval [as render] (common.fs.js?a3d0:73)
    at Components_LazyView$1.render (common.fs.js?a3d0:56)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?db4e:17160)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?db4e:17110)
```

Navigated to source in browser:

```
export function isEmailAndPasswordValid(data) {
    const em = EmailValidation_EmailValidator_Validate_C556D7B(data.Email, false, false);
    const p = !isNullOrWhiteSpace(data.Password);
    if (em) {
        return p;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My F# code :

```
let isEmailAndPasswordValid (data: LoginInfo)=
       let em = EmailValidation.EmailValidator.Validate data.Email
       //let em = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace data.Email |> not
       let p = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace data.Password |> not
       em && p
```

When I use simple String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, everything is fine.
Why I can not use imported code in Fable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://fable.io/docs/your-fable-project/use-a-fable-library.html):

> Please note that not all Nuget libraries will work with Fable. Refer to the library documentation to check if it's Fable-compatible.

A compatible library, [amongst other things](https://fable.io/docs/your-fable-project/author-a-fable-library.html), needs to include its F# source code in the NuGet package so Fable can transpile this to JavaScript.

From what I can see, [`EmailValidation`](https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation) is written in C#, so this isn't going to work.